# Cannot retrieve transition state from cell when rearranging is enabled

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, state

I have a `UITableViewController` inside a Navigation Controller. I'm retrieving the state of the cells in a Class of `UITableViewCell` with the method

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state;
```

which works perfectly fine, however when I enable rearranging the Table View with

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath;
```

the state has the values `0`, `2147483649`, `2147483650` & `2147483651` instead of `0`, `1`, `2` & `3`.

Is there a way to resolve this issue or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The supported states are like below:

```
UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask (0),
UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask (1),
UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask (2), and 
UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask | UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask (3).
```

So these states can be confirmed using the below code :

Below Works for any of the transition states and also handles the swipe to delete gesture as well.

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state {

[super willTransitionToState:state];
if (!cell.editing && !cell.showingDeleteConfirmation) {
    // 0 - UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask
} else if (cell.editing && !cell.showingDeleteConfirmation) {
    // 1 - UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask
} else if (!cell.editing && cell.showingDeleteConfirmation) {
    // 2 - UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask
} else if (cell.editing && cell.showingDeleteConfirmation) {
    // 3 - UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask | UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask

}
}
```